# Use cache instead of saving to database

Tags: plugin-development, performance, caching

With my plugin I am generating and saving a lot of data to a secondary table. Data that can be generated on the fly that is associated with entries. I have noticed a performance hit and was given a suggestion of caching some of that data instead of writing to a database.

Does craft have a built in caching system I can use for accomplishing something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`craft()->cache` can point to any one of several different caching drivers as defined by the   [cacheMethod](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#cacheMethod) config setting.

The available methods are all pretty much stock [Yii provided caching drivers](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/#system.caching), with the exception of [FileCache](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/cache/FileCache), which we've [extended a bit](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/etc/cache/FileCache.php).

Note that FileCache is used by default and its values are saved under the `craft/storage/runtime/cache` folder.

Comment: Would FileCache be a recommended method? And do you normally save data as JSON?

Comment: It's the simplest and most general purpose, but it really depends on the context.  You can save whatever you want in there. Yii/Craft does it's own serialization to the contents before writing it to the file, anyway.